# Does every closed curve contain the vertices of a square?

Tags: geometry, soft-question

This is the question on [Futility Closet](http://www.futilitycloset.com/2012/03/22/corner-market/) 
[image]

Is there really no answer?

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem).

Comment: @RagibZaman thanks

Comment: The question is essentially settled for $C^2$ curves, locally graphical curves if we restrict ourselves to one codimension.  There is still more to be done (rectifiable curves would be interesting).

Comment: Another place to look would be Jason Cantarella's page on the topic http://www.jasoncantarella.com/webpage/index.php?title=Square_Peg_problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to Wikipedia ([inscribed square problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem#cite_note-0)), this is an open problem - that is, we don't currently know the answer. It's known to be true for "nice enough" curves (Stromquist's Theorem).

So it *is* true for e.g. all [piecewise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise) smooth curves, which are the kind we tend to imagine. Stromquist more generally implies an affirmative answer for curves that are piecewise *graphs* (as in $y=f(x)$) *of continuous functions*. Also see [this page](http://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/~markn/squares/) for further discussion.